# Logging full stack trace with Monolog

Tags: php, monolog

I use [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) as a stand-alone library in my application and recently I ran into an issue. Let's say, at some point in my application I catch an exception and I want to log it:

```
$mylogger->error('Exception caught', array('exception' => $exception));
```

This works perfectly except one tiny thing - it doesn't log whole stack trace. Is it possible to log exception's full stack trace using monolog build-in formatters?

Answer (score 45):

Actually since version `1.12.0` it is possible to include stacktrace at your log file: there is new method of `LineFormatter` called `includeStacktraces`.

To use this, you need to overwrite default behaviour of monolog formatter:

**config.yml**

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            formatter: your.monolog.service.id
            (rest of config is as usual)
```

**services.yml**

```
services:
    your.monolog.service.id:
        class: Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter
        calls:
            - [includeStacktraces]
```

Check github for more info:
[Pull request](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/pull/466)

Comment: It also exists in the JsonFormatter

Comment: I've added a [separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46379123/1344955) with the code needed to use said method without a config file. Users aren't allowed to make substantial edits to someone else's answer, but if you want to edit it in I'll remove mine.

Comment: Note that creating an instance is not required anymore, you just have to add `include_stacktraces: true` to your handler, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53101280/7283848)

Comment: Another flavor: instead of using `calls`, use `bind` with `$includeStacktraces: true` :)

Answer (score 22):

You can simply use the config file *(Symfony Bundle)* with the "**include_stacktraces**" parameter:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: info
            channels: ["!event"]
            max_files: 10
            include_stacktraces: true <--- SET TO TRUE
```

**@see** [this commit](https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/commit/ef846fbc83c090f324e4b77a17e6f53521d514f5#diff-f49f31ec8ed644d5f2cca231050ae558)

**@see** [the full schema (configuration)](https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/blob/master/Resources/config/schema/monolog-1.0.xsd)

Comment: but would it also fit to the logstash format?

Answer (score 21):

I have a very simple solution!!!

```
$mylogger->error((string) $exception);
```

Comment: you can even omit (string) calls. At least if you're using Monolog.

Answer (score 12):

Adding to [Tomasz Madeyski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28159215/1344955), this is how you can use it via code only:

```
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\ErrorHandler;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;

$formatter = new LineFormatter(LineFormatter::SIMPLE_FORMAT, LineFormatter::SIMPLE_DATE);
$formatter->includeStacktraces(true); // <--

$stream = new StreamHandler('error.log');
$stream->setFormatter($formatter);

$logger = new Logger('logger');
$logger->pushHandler($stream);
```

Answer (score 8):

No, You cannot log the stack trace using the built-in formatters.  See my question [here](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/issues/296).

If you take a look at `LineFormatter.php` you see that the `normalizeException` method is responsible for grabbing the exception data. So, I had to create a new formatter that extended `LineFormatter`.  Here's the code:

```
<?php

namespace Monolog\Formatter;

use Exception;

class ExceptionLineFormatter extends LineFormatter
{
    protected function normalizeException(Exception $e)
    {
        return 'Message: ' . $e->getMessage() . 
                'Stack Trace: '. $e->getTraceAsString();
    }
}
```

And I initialized my logger like so:

```
$logFile = 'MyLogFile.txt';
$handler = new StreamHandler($logFile);
$handler->setFormatter(new ExceptionLineFormatter);
$log = new Logger('MyLogger');
$handler = self::getStreamHander();
$log->pushHandler($handler);
```

This will will print out your stack trace.

Comment: This answer is outdated ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do it, yes years later...

`$mylogger->error('Exception caught', $exception->getTrace());`

since getTrace() returns an array, which is what Monolog wants.

Comment: For anyone like me who used this, be mindful of the fact that if you're using a Gelf handler this will throw an exception. Due to the fact that the getTrace array starts counting at 0 which is an invalid key within the `GelfMessage::setAdditional()`

Answer (score 2):

The [Upvoted answer works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28159215/1731473), but you are not forced to create a custom service for that.

The `monolog.formatter.line` already exists on Symfony 3.4 full stack. You can simply add a method call on it thanks to the `CompilerPassInterface`:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;

class AppKernel extends Kernel implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->getDefinition('monolog.formatter.line')->addMethodCall('includeStacktraces');
    }
}
```

The monolog handler does not seems to receive the service by default, so you still have to specify it. Example:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: rotating_file
            max_files: 12
            date_format: 'Y-m'
            path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log'
            level: debug
            formatter: monolog.formatter.line
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to log stacktrace **only** when Exception is thrown, you can do this, in the `AppServiceProvider`:

```
public function register()
{
     $logger = Log::getMonolog();
     $logger->pushProcessor(function ($record) {
        if (isset($record['context']['exception']))
        {
            $record['extra']['stacktrace'] = $record['context']['exception']->getTraceAsString();
        }

        return $record;
    });
}
```

This will add the stacktrace to `extra` column, which then can be used per LineFormatter

Answer (score -1):

getTraceAsString will give you the Stack Trace array as a 'End of Line' delimited string.  Explode on PHP_EOL and then foreach through the array logging each element.  Hope this helps.

```
<?php
function test() {
    throw new Exception;
}

try {
    test();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $array = explode(PHP_EOL, $e->getTraceAsString());
    foreach($array as $line){
        $mylogger->error($line);
}
```

Should produce something like this:

```
#0 index.php(14): test()
#1 {main}
```

Comment: This is really not a great idea. In most of the logging tools / formatters it will be pain to debug.